# Why does $x \in F(y)$ imply that $F(y)$ is closed?

Tags: general-topology

From Sundaram, "A first course in optimization theory", 1996, p. 95:

> $$F(y) = \{ x \in R^n_+\ |\ g(x) \ge y,\ x_i \le \epsilon_i \ \text{for all}\ i \}             $$
>   This set $F(y)$ is clearly bounded. The continuity of $g$ implies it is also closed. To see this, let $x^k$ be any sequence in $F(y)$, and let $ x^k \to x$. Then, $g(x^k) \ge x$ for each $k$, which implies by the continuity of $g$ that 
>   $$ g(x) = \lim_{k \to \infty} g(x^k) \ge y $$
>   Moreover, $x^k \ge 0 $ for all $k$ implies $x \ge 0$ by Theorem 1.8. Therefore, $x \in F(y)$, so $F(y)$ is closed.

I feel I can follow the concept all the way to the very last line. 
Isn't it obvious from the definition of $F(y)$ that $x \in F(y)$ ? And if not, how can one imply $F(y)$ being closed?

Comment: I think you may be confused about what "closed" means: what definition are you using?  How would *you* prove a set is closed?

Comment: What I understand is that a set is defined to be closed if it's complement is open.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  It will help a lot to know the following alternative definition (for metric spaces they can be proven equivalent): a set $S$ is closed if it contains all its limit points.

Answer (score 0):

Because "let $ x^k \to x$" means $x \in \overline{F(y)}$. And $x \in F(y)$, then we can conclude that $\overline{F(y)} \subseteq F(y)$, and hence $\overline{F(y)} = F(y)$.

> In fact, it says not clearly. It should say: Let any $x \in \overline{F(y)}$, then there exists a sequence $\{x_k\}_k$ which converges $x$ (as $F(y)$ is first countable), then.......